# Decide whether the argument is valid or a fallacy, and the form that applies.

Tags: logic

If the car is fast, then the thief escapes.
The thief escapes.
$\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_$
$\therefore$ The car is fast.

so

$P \implies Q$
$Q$
$\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_$
$\therefore P$

Decide whether the above argument is valid or a fallacy, and the form that applies.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: This is known as [affirming the consequent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affirming_the_consequent).

Comment: The argument is wrong. P => Q does not mean Q => P .

Comment: It's perfectly clear what is being asked, assuming that one bothers to read the title.

Comment: You didn't know that there are methods of escape that don't involve fast cars?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

What will be happened if $(P\to Q)\wedge Q$ is correct but $P$ is not? In fact, $P$ could be **False**, $Q$ could be **True** and $(P\to Q)\wedge Q$ could be **True** as well.

Answer (score 1):

The argument is invalid. Just because $P$ is a sufficient condition for $Q$, does not mean it is necessary (If it rains the grounds wet, the grounds wet but that does not meant it rained).

Answer (score 1):

This is just a misapplication of the detachment rule (modus ponens). The thief will escape if the car is fast, but this does not rule out the possibility of the thief escaping with a slow car. Or even on foot. You can't conclude that the car is fast given only that the thief escaped.

Answer (score 0):

The argument is a fallacy, because $p\implies q$ does not mean that $q \implies p$. This would only be true for a biconditional statement.

Comment: what kind of invalid fallacy is this? Please

Comment: @MethodManX: It's an example of [*affirming the consequent*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affirming_the_consequent).

Comment: @MethodManX: Fallacy of the converse

Comment: @SujaanKunalan Thank you